# ¿Como preguntar si un checkbox esta seleccionado, si fue creado de manera dinamica?

Tags: android-studio, checkbox

Necesito recorrer una grilla que cree de manera dinámica al agregar un pedido.Pero al eliminar un pedido la manera que pregunto si esta check es a traves de un ciclo de la cantidad de hijos mas el tag que le di al crearlo.

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(view.getContext());
                            cb.setHeight(120);
                            cb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_button);
                            cb.setTag("cb" + i);
                            cb.setText(cb.getTag().toString());
```

Para preguntar si esta check hago lo siguiente y elimino la vista creada por su el tag del LinearLayout

```
 for(int i = 0; i < linear.getchildcount; i++)
                {
                    CheckBox cb = linearLayout.findViewWithTag("cb"+i);
                    if(cb.isSelected())
                    {
                        // ELIMINO LA COLUMNA SELECCIONADA //
                        linearLayout.removeView(linearLayout.findViewWithTag("ly" + i));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Esta Check.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Si genero 3 Checkbox

```
1 cb1
2 cb2
3 cb3
```

Y elimino el item 2

```
1 cb1
3 cb3
```

Al volver a recorrer me da un error ya que no existe el 2.intente cambiarle el tag luego de eliminar a los hijos que quedan pero me da un error.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿2 preguntas, si esta seleccionado y si fue creado dinamicamente? o deseas resolver el problema del error? revisar [ask].

Comment: @Jorgesys Error mio lo copie con el código mal es "isChecked" .Lo creo con un botón, lo solucione eliminando todas las vista y recreándolas denuevo. Aun así el tema de las posiciones me juega en contra por que al eliminar algún pedido del medio. ya que al agregar uno le sumo a posicion+1; si elimino le resto 1. pero como dije antes si posee mas de 3 pedidos, la posicion ya esta en uso y no deja agregar.

Comment: Entonces que es lo que en realidad requieres ? @JuanSepulveda

Comment: Necesita saber recorrer un Linearlayout con sus hijos y no buscarlos por su tag. Gracias por tu tiempo @Jorgesys